# VS Command Line "The Process cannot access the file...because it is being used by another process" build fails

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, build

I've seen a bunch of other questions that are similar to this one regarding VS, but none in regards to the command line.

Using VS Command line (i.e. BuildConsole "SOLUTIONNAME" /BUILD /cfg="CONFIG_SETTINGS" /prf="PROJECTNAME"), I get the highly reproducable (although not 100%) error shown in the question: "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process". However, I only get this error the first 1-5 times I run BuildConsole. It seems to be a timing-related thing. If I run BuildConsole once, then wait a while, then run again, it will work. If I run it 5 times consecutively, it will fail all 5 times or sometimes work on the 5th, depending on how fast the previous runs failed. Also, I can get it to work 100% of the time by opening the solution in VS IDE and then closing the IDE and re-running.

This build command is part of a tool that will report failure if the command fails (which it does, most of the time, although it shouldn't fail). So my question is this: how can I get the BuildConsole command to work the 1st time, 100% of the time? Obviously I don't expect it to work if the solution/project is actually being used by another process, but it should be able to take control from whatever is hanging onto the files.

Comment: Have you tried turning off antivirus software?

Comment: @ScottMcP-MVP I can't. This is at work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not running in administrator mode. When I set my C# program that is running BuildConsole to force admin rights, BuildConsole works every time.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on windows 7, have moved Visual Studio folder from Documents folder to the root of C:\, changed the location in Tools/Options/Help/Import and Export settings to point to the new location, same with Projects and Solutions all pointing to the new location.
No problems with building at all, unless there is an error with the code.

Comment: That seems like a good solution for individual users, so +1. Unfortunately I can't enforce that large of a change at work for everyone using the tool, so it's not really applicable in my situation. I'll try it on my computer though.